# Created Blazor server side project with SSL, how do I switch to non-SSL?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a new Blazor server-side project with SSL but I experience some trouble and would like to fall back to non-SSL version. This is the error message that i get in the browser console:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I also cannot connec to my database, which worked fine with all my other projects. I'd like to eliminate a possible relationship between the SSL setting and the errors.

I removed the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` statement in `Program.cs` but the errors remain. Is there anything else I can do? I'm on VS 2022 with .Net 6 RC2. In vs 2019 there was a flag which I could set in the project properties but I can't find that in 2022.

Comment: Fix the certificate error instead. If you use a self-signed certificate, add it to the list of trusted certificate. HTTPS isn't just about security or preventing browsers from flagging your site as insecure. You can't use HTTP/2 which means your application will slow down significantly. Instead of making multiple HTTP requests eg to load scripts and images, your application will be forced to make the calls one by one

Comment: You can trust the self-signed dev certificate with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Answer (score 1):

I found the SSL option in the menu. They have changed it from VS 2019 to 2022 and it was hard to discover it.

[image]

Comment: The solution is to fix the certificate error, not throw out the baby with the bathwater - and add a significant delay to your application because HTTP/2 no longer works

Comment: Didn't know that, I'll have a look to figure that issue out. Thx!